# Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists - query is broken, not sure why

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

I've written the following:

```
  $email->addValidator('emailAddress', false)
        ->setRequired(true)
        ...
        ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(
            array(
                'table'   => 'site_users',
                'field'   => 'email',
            )
        ));
```

This isn't working and instead I'm getting the following error message:

*Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `site_users` WHERE (`` = 'Test data4') LIMIT 1' at line 1*

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure it'll make much difference, but you have an unnecessary comma after 'email'.  The field in site_users is definitely 'email' I presume?

Comment: Definitely looks like the where clause isn't getting the field name correctly.

Comment: @Chris: You're allowed to do that in PHP! You can have a comma at the end of an array like that. It's a good habit to get into if you often forget to put a comma after adding an item to an array.

Fixed the issue, however! Weird one, mind. I fixed it by swapping the fields round. That is, I put "email" in "table" and "site_users" under "field". That's the wrong way round: email is definitely the field name and the table is definitely "site_users", so it must be some kind of bug. Weird one though!

Comment: As I say - I didn't think it would make any difference - but useful to know its OK.  Also just had a look at the source code for the constructor - full details in answer below (wouldn't fit in a comment).

Comment: FYI: The `site_users` is in the correct place and the table name is missing! Hence, there must be something wrong with the field/email pair. The switcharoo may work but probably for some other weird reasons.

Comment: Adrian: see the comments on the answer I picked. Seems the tutorial/explanation code I read was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a look at the code and found this in the constructor for `Zend_Validate_Db_Abstract` (parent of `Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists`):

```
        $options       = func_get_args();
        $temp['table'] = array_shift($options);
        $temp['field'] = array_shift($options);
        if (!empty($options)) {
            $temp['exclude'] = array_shift($options);
        }

        if (!empty($options)) {
            $temp['adapter'] = array_shift($options);
        }

        $options = $temp;
```

So it expects the options to be in the correct order, and ignores the keys you specify!  Bizarre.  But it looks like your code should have still worked - what version of ZF are you running?

Comment: We're using 1.9.4 here and have no control over that, annoyingly. Thanks for taking a look at the code - that is weird. Maybe if I'm free one night I'll sit down and contribute something back :)

Comment: +1 Interesting - this is a really bad bug and if it hasn't been fixed yet it needs to be! Please submit a bug to the issue tracker.

Comment: @Muu @Chris FYI `func_get_args` would work if you had passed the arguments as single strings and not an array. There is in fact an if clause first `if (func_num_args() > 1)` which is false in this case!

Comment: Ah yes - how did i miss that...  It seemed like such an obvious issue when I saw it...   Looking at [the code from 1.9.4](http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend+Framework&path=%2Ftags%2Frelease-1.9.4%2Flibrary%2FZend%2FValidate%2FDb%2FAbstract.php), the constructor is very different.  It doesn't appear to accept `field` as part of an array.  It looks like you should use `new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists('site_users','email')`.

Comment: Huh. I found similar code (to what I put) on two separate tutorials, no idea where they got that from. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the array handling was added in 1.10, so any recent tutorials could use this format.  Since you're stuck with 1.9, you'll need to use the format specified in my previous comment. (did this work by the way?)

Comment: @Muu, @Chris Interesting. Since you have this older version and looking at the WebSVN your array was expanded into table and schema at `if (is_array($table))`. This makes perfect sense now with your error. The table has been used and set but the field got dropped and was still missing. Unfortunately in that version they did not verify the $field argument.